# Get value from javascript using "getElementById" to java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, e2e-testing

I have a selenium test in java that works fine on DEV environment using a function `findElement(By.xpath("actual xpath")).getAttribute("actual attribute")`, which is getting me a value of an input. I tried the same test run on PROD environment, but it couldn't find this attribute. For some reason the value of this input is not visible anywhere in the xpath. I know the input's id, so I wrote in my browser's console a simple javascript function `document.getElementById("actual id").value` and it returned the correct value that I need, so that information is sadly hidden from java, but not from javascript. Is there a way, how can I use this javascript function in my java code?

Here's what I tried:

```
String id = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='First Name(s)']")).getAttribute("for");
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String method = "\"return document.getElementById('" + id + "').value;\"";
Object name = js.executeScript(method);
```

As you can guess, it didn't work. Object `name` is returning just `null`.
I'm sure that the `id` is correct, verified it by debug, so I had to do a mistake somewhere else.

DEV environment:

```
<input _ngcontent-eqp-c44 class="input-element ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-reflect-model="John" id="input_id_3301863451932101" type="text">
```

I need the value "John" from `ng-reflect-model` which is super easy on this environment, but

PROD environment:

```
<input _ngcontent-xjq-c2 class="input-element ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" id="input_id_6695429395219272" type="text">
```

[There you can see more of the HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iz5In.png)

there is just nothing I can use with java...

Comment: have you tried to find this element by id using WebDriver? driver.findElementById("yourId");?

Comment: @Vault23 I tried `driver.findElement(By.id(id));` to get it as a WebElement, 
but it doesn't include the value I'm looking for and I even tried to add `.getText()` at the end, but I should have known it wouldn't work since the <input> doesn't have `innerHTML`. How stupid of me...

Comment: try ele.getAttribute('value'). it may work.

Comment: is that js working when you run in js-console in browser dev tools?

Comment: Update the question with more of the outerHTML from the _PROD environment_

Comment: @Ciri can you add full `HTML` of the site?

Comment: @DebanjanB I added a screenshot of the HTML from the PROD

Comment: @dafie I added a screenshot with the whole HTML part, that belongs to the input. Hope it's enough

Comment: @Ciri I suppose that the value is stored in different tag.

Comment: @AlexeyR. yes, `document.getElementById("id").value` will give me exactly what I need in js-console in browser dev tools

Comment: @dafie I tried to find that value in HTML file using CTRL+F and it didn't find anything. I can see the value in the web application, I can get the value using javascript in console in browser dev tools... just that stupid HTML file won't give me what I need.

Comment: @Ciri if it is displayed as a text it must be somewhere in html.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try in script something like `elem.getAttribute('ng-reflect-model')`

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer! Thank you all for your cooperation!!
I just had to change the last part of the code `Object name = js.executeScript(method);` with `String name = js.executeScript(method).toString();` so if anybody has the same problem as me, you can get the value of an input in java using javascript and input's ID like this:

```
String id = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='First Name(s)']")).getAttribute("for");
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String method = "return document.getElementById('" + id + "').value;";
String name = js.executeScript(method).toString();
```

Comment: You shouldn't cast `js.executeScript(method).toString()` to `String` since `toString()` returns a `String` object

Comment: @AlexeyR. good point, I'll edit the answer. Thanks!